# Xamarin Forms Grid Positioning

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My code creates the grid just like I want to, but my issue is the formatting of it.  For example, the below syntax has the grid (using iPhone emulator) start at almost the half-way point of the screen.  From best of I can tell, I am only declaring the width of the date column as I do not want it to be drug onto 2 lines if it is a 2 digit month or 2 digit year.

What would be the best way to alter this code so that the grid will span the entire screen in Up & Down format, not Horizontal.

```
    private void LoadInvoiceGrid()
{
    List<InvoiceHistory> IH = new List<InvoiceHistory>();
    IH = dal.GetInvoices(company);

    Grid usergrid = new Grid();

    //Adding in this line makes no diff to the display of the grid
    usergrid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    //

    usergrid.Padding = new Thickness(10, 120, 0, 0);
    usergrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 50 });
    foreach (var item in IH)
        usergrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = 50 });

    usergrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });
    usergrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });
    usergrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 50 });


    Label invoicenumHeader = new Label
    {
        Text = "Invoice #"
    };
    Label invoiceamountHeader = new Label
    {
        Text = "Amount"
    };
    Label invoiceduedateHeader = new Label
    {
        Text = "Due Date"
    };
    Grid.SetColumn(invoicenumHeader, 1);
    Grid.SetColumn(invoiceamountHeader, 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(invoiceduedateHeader, 3);
    usergrid.Children.Add(invoicenumHeader);
    usergrid.Children.Add(invoiceamountHeader);
    usergrid.Children.Add(invoiceduedateHeader);

    int rowIndex = 1;
    foreach (var item in IH)
    {
        string date = item.invoiceduedate.Date.ToShortDateString();

        Label invoicenum = new Label
        {
            Text = item.invoicenum.ToString()
        };
        Label invoiceamount = new Label
        {
            Text = "$" + item.invoiceamt.ToString("0.##")
        };
        Label invoiceduedate = new Label
        {
            Text = date
        };
        Grid.SetRow(invoicenum, rowIndex);
        Grid.SetRow(invoiceamount, rowIndex);
        Grid.SetRow(invoiceduedate, rowIndex);
        Grid.SetColumn(invoicenum, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(invoiceamount, 2);
        Grid.SetColumn(invoiceduedate, 3);
        usergrid.Children.Add(invoicenum);
        usergrid.Children.Add(invoiceamount);
        usergrid.Children.Add(invoiceduedate);
        rowIndex++;
    }
    InvoiceGrid = usergrid;
}
```

**EDIT**
In my XAML I have the Vertical Option set to Fill And Expand and it is not making any difference. See my XAML for the page.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
         x:Class="Pages.DoIt"  >
<ContentPage.Content>  
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30" Spacing="40"> 
    <Label TextColor="#77d065" FontSize = "8" Text="Yes, Test, Text" />
    <Label TextColor="Blue" FontSize="8" Text="{Binding CompanyWelcomeMessage}" />
    <ContentView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Content="{Binding InvoiceGrid,Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0,10,0,0"/>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>  
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: you need to use the grid's VerticalOptions property to control how it is positioned within its parent

Comment: @Jason - sorry I already had that param set in my XAML of the page. I edited my op to show this.

Comment: you don't have it set on the Grid.

Comment: @Jason - if in my C# directly under the instantiation of my Grid() if I add `usergrid.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;` I still see no change in my onscreen display

Comment: the way you're exposing your Grid - via a bound property on the ContentView - may be messing up the Layout engine.  I really don't know.  I've never it done that way.

Comment: @Jason - how would you recommend doing it?

Comment: just put the grid directly in the StackLayout

Comment: I have never done it that way, lol (probably the right way) - I have always used the C# and bind property.